# Syntax error on token in Eclipse

Tags: java

I am trying to use a random number generator for a small game I am writing. The random generator is in an external class to be called by the main.

I am getting a syntax error as indicated below and cant tell why? Any help would be great!

Code:
    import java.util.Random;

```
    public class RandomGenerator 
{
    Random generator = new Random(); // Error here is: Syntax error on token ";", { 
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)          // expected after this token
    {
      int r = generator.nextInt(2);
    }
} // I also get an error here telling me to add an "}"
```

Comment: you miss the function :))

Comment: The line wrapping is not Java style, that's C++ code accent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class RandomGenerator 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Random generator = new Random ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            int r = generator.nextInt (2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put code inside a class without having a method or block around it.
Read this:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Also note that standard Java formatting places opening braces at the end of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this part:

```
    Random generator = new Random(); // Error here is: Syntax error on token ";", { 
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)             expected after this token
{
  int r = generator.nextInt(2);
}
```

be in a function? Like:

```
public static void init()
{
     Random generator = new Random(); 
     int r=0;
     for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)             
     {
         r = generator.nextInt(2);
     }
}
```